# Agregar una columna nueva a una tabla con datos en Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

En Laravel tenemos una migración users que viene por defecto con la siguiente estructura

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

La cual creamos desde consola con el siguiente comando

```
php artisan migrate
```

Esto va a generar que se ejecuten todas las migraciones y por ende se creen todas las tablas, una por cada archivo de migración

Sin embargo, el detalle es el siguiente; yo inserto una fila de datos desde la consola de Maria DB

```
MariaDB [blog]> insert into users(name, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at)
    -> values
    -> ("alfa", "alfa@mail.com", NULL, "dsfdfsfsf", "dfsdf765675", NOW(), NOW());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.077 sec)

MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name | email         | email_verified_at | password  | remember_token | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | alfa | alfa@mail.com |              NULL | dsfdfsfsf | dfsdf765675    | 2018-10-06 14:11:10 | 2018-10-06 14:11:10 |
+----+------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**El problema ahora es**

Necesito agregar una columna a esa tabla llamada *features* de tipo *JSON* pero necesito mantener los datos existentes; por lo tanto no puedo ejecutar la migración de nuevo alterando la estructura original

¿Cómo lo logro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para poder agregar una nueva columna a la tabla `users` requerimos la nueva migración, la cual llamaremos de este modo

> Usando la sintáxis de `add_` podemos diferenciar las migraciones que
>   son para crear de aquellas que son solo para modificar la estructura
>   de una tabla, en este caso el agregar una nueva columna

```
php artisan make:migration add_features_to_users
```

La migración anterior, generará una nueva tabla que como se lee en su nombre servirá para agregar la columna `features` a la tabla `users`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->json('features')
                  ->after('email')
                  ->nullable;
        });
    }
```

Como te das cuenta en el código anterior tenemos las siguientes caracteristicas

1. En vez de usar `Schema::create` usamos `Schema::table` con eso aclaramos a la migración que no queremos hacer una nueva tabla, si no modificar una existente que en este caso se llama `users
2. a la propiedad `$table` le indicamos que agregaremos una nueva columna de tipo json llamada `features`
3. Opcionalmente le podemos indicar después de que columna debe de ir la recién creada en este caso le indicamos que vaya después de la columna email

Una vez hecho lo anterior, ejecutamos el siguiente comando

```
C:\Users\P\app1>php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2018_10_06_191852_add_features_to_users
Migrated:  2018_10_06_191852_add_features_to_users
```

Donde como pueden notar la única migración que encuentra el sistema como pendiente es la de `add_features_to_users` y es la que procesa

Al final si nos vamos de nuevo a la consola de Maria DB y ejecutamos un `describe` de la tabla users veremos la nueva columna recién ingresada

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe users;
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| features          | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_verified_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.008 sec)
```

Si ahora hacemos un `select` a la tabla users veremos que la columna recién ingresada ya aparece sin un valor asignado pero los datos que ya estaban aún se mantienen

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name | email         | features | email_verified_at | password  | remember_token | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | alfa | alfa@mail.com |          |              NULL | dsfdfsfsf | dfsdf765675    | 2018-10-06 14:11:10 | 2018-10-06 14:11:10 |
+----+------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```